# Returning object from function using constructor

Tags: c++

Example class:

```
class myclass
{
  int a;
  int b;

public:
  myclass() {}
  myclass(int x, int y)
  {
    a = x;
    b = y;
  }
};
```

Function:

```
myclass function()
{
  return myclass(2, 3);
}
```

This line I do not understand:

```
 return myclass(2, 3);
```

How is it possible to return object like this? 
Looks like copy constructor is being used but constructors shouldn't return any value? (c++ beginner language please)

Comment: Not sure what you don't understand. It is creating a `myclass` object by calling constructor, and then returning that object from `function()`.

Comment: `myclass(2, 3)` does, sort of, return a class object.  For example you can do `myclass A = myclass(2, 3);`.  It is handing over the address.

Comment: First time I stumbled upon syntax like 'class_name(..)' to find out it returns object? Never saw it being used in any of mine c++ beginner books.

Comment: class_name(...) is a call to the constructor. Notice that the constructor has exactly that name where it is defined in the class definition.

Comment: Thanks, now I at least learned that expressions such as 'myclass obj = myclass(2,3)'  or 'myclass *ptr = &(myclass(2,3));' are valid in C++

Answer (score 1):

The return statement has a [specific syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return): `return` *expression* where *expression* is **convertible to the function return type**.

So `myclass(2, 3)` is convertible to the return type (it is the same type). You could also have used `return {2,3};`.

From the link we also note:

> Returning by value may involve construction and copy/move of a
>   temporary object, unless [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is used.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
return myclass(2, 3);
```

does two things:

1. First a temporary object is created. This is what `myclass(2, 3)` does. It creates an object, calling the appropriate constructor.
2. The temporary object is returned, by value which means it's copied (or more likely the copy is *elided* as part of *return value optimizations*).

Answer (score 0):

`myclass(2, 3)` is an *expression* that evaluates to a new (temporary) object of type `myclass`, constructed by invoking the `myclass::myclass(int, int)` constructor.

`return myclass(2, 3);` uses the value of such expression (the newly constructed `myclass`) as return value of function `function`. This in turn possibly invokes a copy constructor to copy the value from the temporary location where it has been constructed to whatever location is used for the return value ([unless RVO kicks in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization), which should be mandatory in some recent C++ standard).